# Style guidelines for CRAN

Tags: r

I though that the only requirements to upload a package to the CRAN was to follow the [repository policies](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/policies.html) and to pass a `R CMD check --as-cran`, without any errors, warnings, or notes.

But shortly after I sent my package via the [submission form](https://cran.r-project.org/submit.html), I received an email telling me that when I refer to functions, I have to write their names with parenthesis, ie: talking about `print()` instead of `print`.

So it seems that there exist style guidelines for writing description, vignettes or documentation.

I don't want to waste the time of CRAN maintainers, nor mine, by having a long email exchange. However, I can't find such guidelines on the internet.

*Where can I find them?*

Comment: Give an example of how you are referring to functions. In a usage section? Or in a description section?

Comment: I refer to them almost everywhere, I don't know which part the reviewer was talking about. For instance I wrote "Introduces some and none, as well as match_with from functional languages." in the description.

But I corrected that, and this ain't really the question here. I just need a exhaustive, canonical list of all the style rules I have to follow.

Comment: There isn't one. Read Writing R Extensions, following the Repo Policy, keep an eye on the r-package-devel list.  Sometimes _things change_ and new requirements get added.  _C'est la vie_, and its better in the long run.